# Copy file to remote host through intermediate (jump) host

Tags: linux, unix, ssh, scp

Now I am connecting to endpoint using this command:

```
ssh my.jumphost.com -t 'export iip=111.22.3.44; bash'
```

The problem is that I don't have direct access to this IP, I mean I can't just ssh 111.22.3.44 from my jumphost. So basically I can reach destination host only if I export this variable with IP address from jumphost.
I've already looked into `scp` command and the way with `ssh` tunnel, but seems like both of them are required direct access to destination host.

I've also tried

```
cat test.py | ssh my.jumphost.com -t 'export iip=111.22.3.44' 'cat > /home/user/test.py'
```

but in that case file is being copied to jumphost only.

Any advice or guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: try create ssh tunnel first `ssh my.jumphost.com -L 12345:111.22.3.44:22` and then scp through the tunnel in another terminal: `scp -P 12345 test.py localhost:`

Comment: @ZabojCampula unfortunately it doesn't work, got an error `Permission denied (publickey)` when I try to `scp`